# How to run a logistic regression by groups using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, linear-regression, logistic-regression, glm

I have a tree database containing the number of cells in different growth stages (enlarging, thickening and maturing) for different trees during many years. I went to collect data certain days of the year (DOY; January 1 would be DOY 1, January 2 would be DOY 2, etc.). I simplificated it like this to make a reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame("Year" = c(2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012,
                            2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013,
                            2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013),
                 "Tree" = c(15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 41, 41,
                            41, 41, 41, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53),
                 "DOY" = c(65, 97, 125, 177, 214, 65, 97, 125, 177, 214,
                           61, 99, 118, 166, 221, 61, 99, 118, 166, 221),
                 "Enlarging" = c(0, 2, 4, 5, 0, 0, 3, 6, 3, 0, 0, 5, 4, 4, 0, 0, 4, 7, 5, 0),
                 "Thickening" = c(0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 2, 4, 2, 0),
                 "Maturing" = c(0, 0, 3, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 3, 6, 8, 0, 0, 0, 4, 7, 0))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(Year = as.factor(Year),
         Tree = as.factor(Tree),
         DOY = as.numeric(DOY),
         Enlarging = as.numeric(Enlarging),
         Maturing = as.numeric(Maturing))

print(df)
   Year Tree DOY Enlarging Thickening Maturing
1  2012   15  65         0          0        0
2  2012   15  97         2          0        0
3  2012   15 125         4          2        3
4  2012   15 177         5          4        7
5  2012   15 214         0          0        0
6  2012   22  65         0          0        0
7  2012   22  97         3          0        0
8  2012   22 125         6          4        3
9  2012   22 177         3          3        4
10 2012   22 214         0          0        0
11 2013   41  61         0          0        0
12 2013   41  99         5          0        3
13 2013   41 118         4          3        6
14 2013   41 166         4          2        8
15 2013   41 221         0          0        0
16 2013   53  61         0          0        0
17 2013   53  99         4          2        0
18 2013   53 118         7          4        4
19 2013   53 166         5          2        7
20 2013   53 221         0          0        0
```

I would like to apply **separate** logistic regression between every growth stage nº of cells and the DOY (for enlarging, for example: Enlarging ~ DOY) for every different tree, every year. I have tried a few things, for example grouping by Year and Tree and applying a logistic regression for every growth stage, one by one:

```
df_enlarging <- df %>%
  select(Tree, Year, Enlarging)%>%
  group_by(Tree, Year)%>%
  mutate(the_glm = glm(Enlarging ~ DOY, family = "binomial", data = df),
         Fitted = predict(the_glm, type = "response"))
```

Also tried pivoting my data, nesting it (so I can apply the logistic regression for the three growth stages at the same time for every tree of every year) and doing the same same later, like this:

```
df_long <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(Enlarging:Mature,
               names_to = 'Growth_Phase',
               values_to = 'Count') %>%
  ungroup()


df_nested <- df_long %>%
  nest_by(Year, Tree, as.factor(Growth_Phase)) #tried converting growth_phase to factor also

df_glm <- df_nested %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(the_glm = list(glm(Count ~ DOY, family = "binomial", data = data)),
         Fitted = list(predict(the_glm, type = "response")))
```

None of this worked and in both cases I got the same error: `` Problem while computing `the_glm = glm(Enlarging ~ DOY, family = "binomial", data = data). Caused by error: ! y values must be 0 <= y <= 1 `` . Does anyone know what can I do to fix this? Thank you so much.

Comment: A binomial glm model expects a binary response variable: 0 or 1. That's why you're getting that error. Are you sure you don't want a model for counts, like a Poisson family?

Comment: Hi! Could I convert my database into a presence/absence database (0-absence, 1-presence) and use this type of model this way? @joran

Answer (score 1):

first per joran - yes this will be easiest if you change your data to 1/0.

i'm accomplishing that by removing the data with 0 then, "uncounting" the data, defining the new lines as 1, then adding the 0 data back in. after that it is a simple matter of grouping then mapping the model via `purrr`, using `broom` to clean up results and predict on the dataset.

```
df %>% 
  filter(Enlarging==0) -> e0

df %>% 
  anti_join(e0) %>% 
  uncount(Enlarging) %>% 
  mutate(Enlarging = 1) %>% 
  bind_rows(e0) %>% 
  mutate(Year = as.factor(Year),
         Tree = as.factor(Tree),
         DOY = as.numeric(DOY),
         Enlarging = as.numeric(Enlarging),
         Maturing = as.numeric(Maturing)) %>% 
  group_nest(Tree, Year) %>% 
  mutate(the_glm = map(data, ~glm(Enlarging~DOY, family="binomial", data = .)),
         result = map(the_glm, broom::tidy),
         glance = map(the_glm, broom::glance),
         fits = map(the_glm, broom::augment, type.predict = "response")) %>% 
  unnest(fits)
```

Comment: Hello @B Williams . Thank you so much for your help with the code. I have a question, this code is to extract glm predictions for the enlarging phase, right? But why writing code for the maturing one too while using `mutate`? Should I apply this same code later also for the thickening and the mature phases?

Comment: you could do all of your models at the same time, but that circles back to the data aspects where all of this will be easier if you turn your data into a binary format